# Как проверить список списков на наличие дубликатов

Tags: python, list

Есть List[List[int]].
Например `check([[1 1], [3], [2 2]])` - вернет True, тк дубликатов нет;

`check([[1 1], [3], [2 2], [3]])` - False, тк есть 3
Пытался через set что то реализовать но ругается что list unhashable. Какие есть варианты?

Внутри только список из одинаковых чисел

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки решения, что вы пробовали и что именно не получилось?

Comment: а в таком случае `[[1,2], [2,1]]` ?

Comment: Такого по условию не будет. Внутри только список из одинаковых чисел.

Comment: `len(lst) == len(set(map(tuple, lst)))`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def check(arr):
    arr = [(el[0], len(el)) for el in arr]
    return len(arr) == len(set(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_duplicates(lists):
    for l in lists:
        if len(l) != len(set(l)):
            return True
    return False

lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
print(has_duplicates(lists)) # Output: True
```

Comment: Печатает `False`.

Comment: Ты ищешь дубликаты в хотя бы одном из списков, а в вопросе другая задача

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант:

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import List


def check_duplicates(lst: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    cnt = Counter(list(map(tuple, lst)))
    for (k, v) in cnt.items():
        if v > 1:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: `Counter(list(...))` -> `Counter(...)`

Comment: `for (k, v) in cnt.items():` -> `for v in cnt.values():`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy гуд!